# Css not loading after theme installation

Tags: magento2

I m unable to load style-l.css or any css file.I put fresh installation .htaccess but no luck. It show 404 Error.

http://reliancesolution.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Sm/clickboom/en_US/css/styles-l.css

Comment: Did you checked my answer ? Is it helpful for you or not?

Comment: Rohan i check my apache log and there i found some code issue in .htaccess under pub.I just remove .htaccress and now its all ok.

Comment: okay. Happy to help :) Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1) =>** `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**Step 2) =>** `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

**Step 3) =>** make sure apache "rewrite_module" is enabled and then restart the server

**Step 4) =>** Delete cache folder under var/cache

Answer (score 0):

Step1 :- Go to var folder and check .htaccess file is available or not. If it is not available then copy .htaccess file in default magento2 and paste.

Step2 :- Go to pub\static folder and check .htaccess file is available or not. If it is not available then copy .htaccess file in default magento2 and paste.

Step3 :- Login your ssh/putty and go to root directory and run below command

```
a). rm -rf var/*

b). rm -rf pub/static/*

c). php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

d). chmod -R 777 var pub/static
```

Step4 :- Refresh your link after check it

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Check Your .htaccess file at Following locations :

1. Magento Root
2. app/
3. pub/
4. pub/static/

If any of this is not available add them.

Answer (score 0):

Login your ssh/putty and go to root directory and run below command

a). rm -rf var/*

b). rm -rf pub/static/*

c). php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

d). chmod -R 777 var pub/static

Refresh your link.